# Widen notification popup in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, user-interface, shiny

How do I widen notifications in R Shiny? Right now it's cutting off longer error messages.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("test", "Test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$test, {
      showNotification("You did it! Now make me wider", type = "message")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS to adjust width of shiny notification

```
/* Put shiny notifications front and center */
#shiny-notification-panel {
  top: 0;
  bottom: unset;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}
```